# Deleting manually Web Analytics Service Application & Reporting DB files ?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-analytics

I have huge amount of Web Analytics Service Application & Reporting DB files in my sharepoint2010 server. Can i delete manually them or is there a process for this ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way,

1. Stop the Web Analytics Service using Central Administration Tool
2. Open MS SQL Server Management Tool
3. Find the related database
4. Right click, tasks > shrink > Files
5. On the opening window select file type as LOG.

I hope it helps